# running cmd application minimized not work

Tags: c#

I have a cmd application when i pressed insert while aplication is maximized run normal
but when application is minimized not work

What could I do

please help me

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class MainClass 
{
   static void Main()
   {
      ConsoleKeyInfo keypress;
      keypress = Console.ReadKey(); // read keystrokes 

      if (keypress.Key == ConsoleKey.Insert)
      {
         Console.Write("One ");
      }
   }
}
```

not recognized key insert while is minimized

Comment: The negative voting is stupid here. If you - downvoters - will use your brain, you will know what the author need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, you are looking for [Global Hooks](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7294/Processing-Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Hooks-in-C).

Answer (score 2):

How can it work when the command line is minimized? It doesn't have any focus and your key strokes aren't registered.

The same can be said for almost any program - try it with notepad for instance

**Edit:** if you want to register to global key events, use glob hooks like TcKs suggested

Comment: that I have as options that could program what kind of application might create

I need it to work when minimized

Comment: It's hard to understand what you're saying, but your request is simply not possible - it's just how windows **console** works